# How do I combine SSH agent forwarding and gpg-agent?

Tags: gpg, ssh-agent

I have an ssh-agent running on my local machine. I connect to a remote machine via SSH, with agent forwarding enabled. On that remote there is an instance of gpg-agent running.

I know that recent versions of gpg-agent (2.1+) have the command-line flag `--extra-socket` which you can use have the agent retrieve not only the keys added to it, but also keys from a forwarded gpg-agent.

However, I don't have gpg-agent running on my local machine; I have ssh-agent. Is there a way to have gpg-agent retrieve SSH keys from that forwarded ssh-agent?

Comment: Btw, I don't think this is a dupe of http://serverfault.com/q/670224/1253. This asks about gpg-agent compatibility with ssh-agent, while the other asks about `--extra-socket` functionality in ssh-agent itself.